# Adding computed keys in a collection with lodash

Tags: javascript, collections, lodash

Having the following example collection:

```
var data = [ 
  { 'fabrication_order' : 'A', 'start_date' : '2018-03-10 09:00:00', 'end_date' : '2018-04-12 10:30:00', 'product_family': 'car', 'price' : 70},
  { 'fabrication_order' : 'B', 'start_date' : '2018-03-14 12:00:00', 'end_date' : '2018-04-16 13:30:00', 'product_family': 'bike', 'price' : 20},
  { 'fabrication_order' : 'C', 'start_date' : '2018-03-14 13:00:00', 'end_date' : '2018-04-14 13:30:00', 'product_family': 'bike', 'price' : 20}
]
```

I can make stats using lodash :

```
stats = _(data)
   .groupBy('product_family')
   .map((objs, key) => ({
   'product_family' : key,
   'sum_price' : _.sumBy(objs, 'price')
   }))
   .value();
```

> [ { "product_family": "car", "sum_price": 70 }, { "product_family": "bike", "sum_price": 40 } ]

Great. But what if I wanted to calculate the production duration. Is the only way is to transform my input data (before using lodash) by adding the custom fields :

```
data = data.forEach(function(element){
element['production_duration'] = moment(element.end_date).diff(moment(element.start_date), 'hours')
})
```

Or is there a more efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather use `lodash` for the whole thing.

You could have use the `map` method to add the duration property for each item  as you almost did but the best is to use another `sumBy` in your last `map` call.
 What you maybe missed is that you can use a lambda with that function instead of the property name.

```
stats = _(data)
   .groupBy('product_family')
   .map((objs, key) => ({
   'product_family' : key,
   'sum_price' : _.sumBy(objs, 'price'),
   'sum_duration' : _.sumBy(objs, 
          (obj) => (moment(obj.end_date).diff(moment(obj.start_date), 'hours')))
   }))
   .value();
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was hopping for !